# Passing options to Blender when used as py module?

Tags: python

I used to use standalone Blender on my Ubuntu server, like this

```
blender -noaudio --background --python ...
```

Recently I built Blender from source so that I can use it as a normal python module. I can now do

```
python -c 'import bpy'
```

My question is, how do I apply the `-noaudio` flag now?

Also related (Re. the `--background` flag), when I did `blender --background`, a default scene was created in my "workspace." How do I replicate that default scene in my current invocation?

Comment: What is the bigger picture here? Why are you importing Blender this way, rather than simply using the `--python` option? What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a Python pipeline that relies on many modules already installed in my Anaconda Python, so I don't want to reconfigure the Blender Python.